Proving pairwise independence for random matrix hash functions
Let $H_n^m$ be the family of hash functions with $h(x) = Ax + b$ for $A \in \mathbb{Z}_2^{m \times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{Z}_2^m$. I'm trying to prove that this family of hash functions is pairwise-independent. Specifically, for $x_1 \neq x_2$:
$$\mathrm{Pr}_{h}\left[ h(x_1) = y_1 \land h(x_2) = y_2 \right] = \left( \frac{1}{2^m} \right)^2,$$
where the probability is over choosing $h \in H_n^m$ uniformly. I'm having trouble proving pairwise independence. I imagine we can argue something like: We have $Ax_1 + b = y_1$ and $Ax_2 + b = y_2$, so we can combine them together to get $A(x_1 + x_2) = (y_1 + y_2)$. Since $x_1 + x_2 \neq 0$, that means there's a $1/2$ chance the random $A$ satisfies the matrix equation for each linear equation. That means we have a factor of $1/2^m$. We then still have the requirement that $b = Ax_1 + y_1$, which I imagine should bring another factor out, giving the result. However, I'd like to tighten the argument.
Additionally, on slide 16 of these lecture notes, they state that taking $h(x) = Ax$ isn't enough to be 2-universal (which is the same as pairwise independent, from what I understand). Why do we require sampling a random $b$?
This question is similar, though it wasn't clear to me if this applies to matrices as well.
